# Any Jeffrey Nordling appearance in Star Trek The Next Generation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

I have just started watching (along with my wife) DS9 after about two weeks break since ending watching entire TNG. When we started watching "[Past Prologue](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Past_Prologue_(episode))", my wife recalls that she saw the same actor ([Jeffrey Nordling](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jeffrey_Nordling)) in at least one TNG episode.

Is that true or did she made a mistake? I can't find any reference about appearance of this actor anywhere outside DS9.

Comment: He does look slightly like the guy who played T'Jon in Symbiosis: http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/T%27Jon

Comment: I was thinking he looked a bit like Jev from TNG: Violations

Comment: I believe the actor she thought was Nordling was actually Timothy Carhart, playing Lt Commander Hobson in REDEMPTION episode of TNG. They look and act very much alike. I had to look it up to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going through [this list](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/fullcredits) on IMDB, it seems not.  Considering that this list includes all people in *The Next Generation*, including those uncredited, I doubt that Nordling was involved in any *The Next Generation* episodes.  Potentially Nordling looks similar to someone else who was in an episode of TNG, but we can be fairly certain that Nordling himself was not involved!

Comment: We can't, of course exclude that he was in a deleted scene or was cast to help someone run lines.

Comment: @Richard good point!

Comment: That said, Trejder's wife couldn't possibly have seen him in a deleted/cut scene.

Comment: @Richard: Unless it was in DVD "extras"...

Comment: No, we haven't. No deleted scenes / extras. Thus, she must mistaken this guy with some other actor, looking slightly similar, as suggested in comments to question.